# Is it possible to add multiple Title cards to a page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, image-display, title

When a new page is created, there is a really nice looking title piece as shown below. Is there a way to add more instances of this on the page?

[image: Screenshot Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's possible, but you can always use a Content Editor Web Part with JavaScript to duplicate that.